# How to split a string and perform a JOIN using the components?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Mariadb version 10.3.34.
SQL to create the example tables is on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/schplurtz/5c7a09efe93b512ceeecbf623619d4cd).

I have to work with a foreign database on which I have no control. So suggestions to modify the structure of the DB are, sadly, unacceptable. I can add functions, though.

Now, in this database, things can have from 0 to n colors, and the color references are coded as a string of all values joined by a `|` char, like this :

```
+----------------------+
|          things      |
| name (pkey)| colorsid|
+------------+---------+
| 'door'     | '20|5'  |
| 'car'      | '10'    |
| 'hammer'   | null    |
| 'box'      | '5'     |
+------------+---------+

+------------------+
|    colors        |
| id   | color     |
+------+–––––––––––+
| 5    | 'red'     |
| 10   | 'blue'    |
| 20   | 'black'   |
+------+–––––––––––+
```

So the door is black and red, the car is blue, the hammer has no color, and the box is red.

How to “JOIN” on each color code for each thing ?

I'd like a query whose result is this :

```
+---------------------------+
|       thingsandcolors     |
| name       | colornames   |
+------------+--------------+
| 'door'     | 'black|red'  |
| 'car'      | 'blue'       |
| 'hammer'   | null         |
| 'box'      | 'red'        |
+------------+--------------+
```

Performance is not an issue (to a reasonable extent, of course). The DB is expected to contain at most a few tens of colors, and no more than 10 000 things.

Comment: don't save delimited data in columns see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: can't you read ? I have no choice. That is how the db is.

Comment: that is why i posted the link, you nee to split the text (there a tons of functions) and then join the tables. also you have two questions, allowed is only one

Comment: OK. removed the second question and will post a new question. I know what I have to do, split the string and join. I've already spent time trying to do that. But I can't. So I ask. Your link does not give the slightest clue as how to do it. All there is is "this is bad", "this is not in normal form", "this has drawbacks" and so on. All true, all useless

Comment: like i said first split the delimted column into rows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows second join the second table third GROUP_COMCAT the result of the join, that is in a nutshell all you need to do

Comment: thanks @nbk, I've started to try things based on this answer. json_table is very interesting. I have to go to work now, but will most probably continue this evening.